# How to pass both the input's event and an argument to a function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Hello I am trying to pass an input's event and another object as arguments to a change handler function.it works fine if you only pass e (I mean event) to function ,but when I try to add the second argument the first argument that is the Event disappears .I don't know what to pass as the first argument to fit as event. here is the code:

this is the function

```
const changeHandler = (event, secondArgument) => {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(secondArgument);
    }
```

and this is the jsx

```
 <input onChange={() => changeHandler(don't know what to pass here,myArgument)} name='name'} />
```

Comment: Hope this blog will answer you problem: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-onchange-multiple-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the event as the argument to `onChange`. So, you can do something like this

```
<input 
  onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e, "whatever you want")} 
  name='name' 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
     <input 
      onChange={(event) => changeHandler(event, 'props/state/variables') 
      name='name'
    />
```